# Keeping the state of a QCheckBox after closing the GUI

Tags: c++, qt, savestate

In Qt C++ builder, how can I keep the state of a `QCheckBox` after closing the Gui, so it will remain to the previous state when I run it again

Comment: Hi Hanieh, if you read [ask] carefully, you will know that **you must show your efforts** if you want your question to be regarded as positive with the community.

Comment: You may be looking for [`QSettings`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html)

Answer (score 0):

Save it somewhere and load it again on the next run. You can use a plain file, QSettings, a database, whatever you like - but there's no magic just "do it for me" box that you can tick; you're going to have to write some code to preserve and restore the value yourself.